# Laravel 7 | Some recipients receive empty emails

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

I have an laravel 7 application and use smtp with google services to send my emails.

However some clients receive the emails with attachments, but no body. The content of the email is completely blank. Most mail platforms (hotmail, outlook, gmail, mail on mac) receive the complete email. It's just some mail providers receive the email without a body.

I believe this might have to do with some security measures or not supporting HTML emails.

How can I ensure that also these clients receive my emails?

I use `.blade.php` files to send my emails.

example of one of my email files:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CandidateMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message_details)
    {
        //

        $this->message_details = $message_details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $email = $this->view('mail/candidate')
            ->subject($this->message_details['subject'])
            ->with(['message_details' => $this->message_details]);

        if ($this->message_details['attachments']) {
            $email->attachFromStorage($this->message_details['attachments']);
        }

        return $email;
    }
}
```

Fix for outlook (desktop).

replaced my divs with table/tr/td. Now email content is displayed to clients with outlook (desktop).

Answer (score 0):

you had to build your constructor the variable $message_details does not return anything,

```
public $message_details = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to declare public property `public $message_details` [here details](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#view-data)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CandidateMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $message_details;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message_details)
    {
        //

        $this->message_details = $message_details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $email = $this->view('mail/candidate')
            ->subject($this->message_details['subject'])
            ->with(['message_details' => $this->message_details]);

        if ($this->message_details['attachments']) {
            $email->attachFromStorage($this->message_details['attachments']);
        }

        return $email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nay, the email body/content is received on most mail platforms (hotmail, outlook, gmail, mail on mac). It's just some company mail providers that don't receive a body.

Comment: I think that your code have no problem ,  it may be those company mail server problem

Comment: which app you use to that company mail, you should test with another mail client [link] (https://www.thunderbird.net) or other mail client app